# PostgreSQL installation on Windows using Packer exits early during installation with no errors

Tags: postgresql, windows, packer, chocolatey

I am trying to install Postgres (preferably version 12.x, but neither latest nor older versions seem to work) on a Windows Server 2019 VM using Packer. This Packer build installs several other tools without issue, but for some reason appears to just quit the Postgres installation in the middle of it. I've confirmed the install isn't waiting on input or erroring out, the last message in console is just `Installing postgresql12...` before proceeding to the next stage in my Packer build. Running the install manually without packer when remote'd into the machine shows the same message, and then more information after it which is why I know the process is quitting early. Also, when checking install files after Packer is finished, it is missing a large part of the setup and the Postgresql service is not running, so the install is clearly not succeeding.

I have run Packer with debug flags and with more verbosity, nothing stands out. The packer build SEEMS to run perfectly fine before suddenly moving on without finishing the Postgres install. I suspect that some part of the installer is sending a flag that Packer listens for to tell if the installation is done, but I do not know how to check if that is the case. Even if it is, I have tried solutions for this problem such as putting the install in a `Start-Process -FilePath ...` but this appears to be for specifically MSI installers and does not help.

The install was tested with both a Chocolatey package for multiple versions and the exe installer with unattended flags for multiple versions.

Any help for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is your problem:

> Running the install manually without packer when remote'd into the machine shows the same message, and then more information after it which is why I know the process is quitting early

You need to fix this. Packer or Chocolatey CLI is not going to work if the installation is failing.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. The installation IS working when I run it locally in the machine. I mentioned this to communicate how I knew the install was getting cut short.

The install does work when run locally but not when run with packer.

Comment: So you need to remove Packer and Chocolatey from the equation. Chocolatey is easier. Does the Chocolatey package install work?

Comment: As I said, yes it does work.